# Какой знак препинания здесь нужен?

Tags: пунктуация, выбор-варианта

Дано предложение:

> Любовь (?) такая любовь.

Что лучше поставить вместо вопросительного знака: тире, запятую или что-то еще?

Comment: Смысл предложения неясен.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что выбор знака зависит от контекста, от того смысла, который вы хотите передать, и от интонаций, которые вы хотите обозначить. Предложение можно считать [неполным](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/722-26_nepolnye_predlozheniya.html), оно выглядит как ответ на чей-то вопрос.
Если оставить конечную точку неизменной, то я вижу такие пунктуационные варианты:
*Любовь. Такая любовь.

Любовь... Такая любовь.

Любовь, такая любовь.*

Теоретически можно и восклицательный знак поставить:
— Мама! Почему все так несправедливо? Что же это?
— Любовь! Такая любовь.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше поставить запятую. При повторении слов именно она используется.